# Ubuntu crashed basic commands not recognized

Tags: data-recovery, crash

I am relatively new to ubuntu.
I have been working with Biolinux8 that uses Ubuntu 14.
Few days ago it crashed and since then I cannot access the graphic interface anymore.
When I boot I am directly on the command line.

I tried to save my data, compressing them and saving them on usb.
The problem is that Ubuntu does not recognize basic commands like:

```
sudo
```

or

```
ls lsusb
```

The error message I get is simply

```
zsh: command not found: ls
```

I have reset my PATH via

```
source /etc/environment
```

but still

```
sudo lsusb
```

gives me the same error.

I have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions?I wuld be also more than happy to use an external program to recover my data for the hd.

**Update**

I tried

```
su
```

this command is recognized, but when I try to write the usual passwd i used for sudo I get:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekinghikis1f2t4/ubuntu_2.png?dl=0) the result of

```
echo $PATH
/bin/echo $PATH
```

Comment: "does not recognize"... "are not working" so what happens, exactly? are there any error messages? if so please include them in your post

Comment: Deleted my answer to attract more experienced people that can help you...

Comment: Can you run /bin/echo $PATH  ? Just to make sure, first of all what is set in your $PATH.